# How to iterate through an array in MIPS without knowing the size?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips, mips32

I'm working on an assignment to calculate a polynomial using loops and functions in MIPS. Basically the idea is to recreate this Java code:

```
public static void getPolynomial(int n, int x[], int c[] ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println( "p(" +  x[i] +  ") = " +  calcPoly(c, x[i]) );
    }
}
```

where n is the size of the array, x[] is an array of arguments (x vals) for the polynomial, and c[] is an array of coefficients. calcPoly should calculate the polynomial given the array of coefficients and the *current* x-value.

I have a rough understanding of loops/functions so I think I do this given hard-coded sizes (like if I know the array size is 3, I could write calcPoly so that it calculates a 3rd power polynomial). But we have to test the program using different sized arrays, which means calcPoly will need some kind of loop right?

Given `calcPoly(c, x[i]) )` is only passing in c[] and x[i], how would I get the size of c[] within calcPoly? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? I just have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: You can't iterate through **any** array without knowing its size.  Arrays in Java are objects which contain meta-data including their length.  If you're doing this in assembly you'll have to manage that information yourself.

Comment: If you were doing this in C where arrays work like asm (just pointers), you'd need another arg to both functions, passing the degree of the polynomial (number of coefficients), just like how you have an `int n` arg.  This code is only usable with Java arrays which contain their own length, not with asm.  (Unless you implement a struct with a pointer and length, and pass that around where the source passes arrays, in which case it's weird that there's a separate `int n`.)